# Nilpotent and solvable groups

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a finitley generated group say by $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, then $G$ is abelian if 
$x_i$ and $x_j$ commute for every $i,j$. This measn we can check if $G$ is abelian by just looking at the generators.

Is there a similar condition which enables to check that the group is solvable or nilpotent
by looking at the generators only?

Comment: You can check that a group is nilpotent of class at most $k$ by checking  that all commutators $[x_{n_1},x_{n_2}, \ldots , x_{n_{k+1}}]$ of length $k+1$ between the generators are trivial. The test for abelian that you mentioned is just the case $k=1$. I don't think there is such a test for solvability.

Answer (score 2):

As Derek has mentioned, you can check whether $G$ is $k$-step nilpotent by testing some finite family of relations (explicit and depending on $k$) on the generators.

This cannot be done in the solvable case, because if you take the free metabelian group on 2 generators, it is not finitely presented and furthermore, is not quotient of any finitely presented solvable group. Thus you cannot test 2-step solvability this way.

On the other hand, even the nilpotent case has a negative answer if you stick to pairs of generators. Indeed, if you take a finite Coxeter diagram with all edges labeled by some power of 2, outside a small finite list of exceptions, (for instance you can take the full graph on 4 vertices, all edges being labeled by 4), then the resulting Coxeter group $W$ has the property that any two generators generate a nilpotent group (some dihedral 2-group), while $W$ is not solvable (it contains a nonabelian free subgroup).